# How would you model bitmask parameter using URL query string?

Tags: web-services, query-string, bitmask

I'm working on a web service that needs to accept categories and perform a search using those. Categories can be combined, hence bitmask comes to mind.

Example:

```
Spring = 1, Summer = 2, Autumn = 4, Winter = 8
```

Possible options:

1. `?categories=5` - not very user friendly/pretty
2. `?categories=1,4` - needs special parsing
3. `?categories=1&categories=4` - well supported but a bit verbose for a lot of categories
4. `?categories=Spring,Autumn` - seems most user friendly

Is there any standard way or preferred way to model bitmask type data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest going for semantic clarity over compression, but leverage native functions like JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() and model them as an array, e.g.

```
categories = ['spring', 'summer', 'winter']
```

This is like #4, but slightly different in that it's using JSON which you can generate and parse unambiguously.